# Light GBM and Random Forest Model Stacking. Attempting to use a Booster which no longer exists

Tags: r, random-forest, purrr, prediction, lightgbm

I am attempting to use library(stacks) to model stack random forest with Light GBM.
I was able to get all the way to putting my_stack into predict(). Where I got this error:

> ```
> Error in `purrr::map()`:
> ℹ In index: 1.
> ℹ With name: lightGBM_models_1_047.
> Caused by error in `predictor$predict()`:
> ! Attempting to use a Booster which no longer exists. This can happen if you have called Booster$finalize() or if this Booster was saved with saveRDS(). To avoid this error in the future, use saveRDS.lgb.Booster() or Booster$save_model() to save lightgbm Boosters.
> ```
>
> From what I have read this error usually comes from trying to save a lightgbm model for later reuse. Im not sure why I was able to run the stack() after I set up the workflows, and even compare their predictions as it returns how many identical predictions they had and were removed from the data stack, but not be able to use the stack_mod for prediction because the lightgbm booster is gone? Where did it go?

```
`
> randforest_models <- rand_forest_wf %>%
+   tune_grid(resamples=folds,
+             grid=rand_forest_tuning_grid,
+             metrics=metric_set(roc_auc),
+             control = untunedModel)
ℹ The workflow being saved contains a recipe, which is 19.3 Mb in memory. If this ℹ was not
intentional, please set the control setting `save_workflow = FALSE`.
> lightGBM_models <- boost_workflow %>%
+   tune_grid(resamples=folds,
+             grid=boost_tuning_grid,
+             metrics=metric_set(gain_capture),
+             control = untunedModel)
ℹ The workflow being saved contains a recipe, which is 19.3 Mb in memory. If this ℹ was not
intentional, please set the control setting `save_workflow = FALSE`.
Warning messages:
1: In for (v in val) { :
  closing unused connection 12 (<-DESKTOP-3UVUISO:11780)
2: In for (v in val) { :
  closing unused connection 11 (<-DESKTOP-3UVUISO:11780)
3: In for (v in val) { :
  closing unused connection 10 (<-DESKTOP-3UVUISO:11780)
4: In for (v in val) { :
  closing unused connection 9 (<-DESKTOP-3UVUISO:11780)
5: In for (v in val) { :
  closing unused connection 8 (<-DESKTOP-3UVUISO:11780)
6: In for (v in val) { :
  closing unused connection 7 (<-DESKTOP-3UVUISO:11780)
7: In for (v in val) { :
  closing unused connection 6 (<-DESKTOP-3UVUISO:11780)
8: In for (v in val) { :
  closing unused connection 5 (<-DESKTOP-3UVUISO:11780)
9: In for (v in val) { :
  closing unused connection 4 (<-DESKTOP-3UVUISO:11780)
10: In for (v in val) { :
  closing unused connection 3 (<-DESKTOP-3UVUISO:11780)
> 
> 
> my_stack <- stacks() %>%
+   add_candidates(lightGBM_models) %>%
+   add_candidates(randforest_models)
Warning message:
Predictions from 34 candidates were identical to those from existing candidates and were removed from
the data stack. 
> 
> stack_mod <- my_stack %>%
+   blend_predictions() %>%
+   fit_members()

> car_predictions <- predict(stack_mod, new_data=test, type='prob') %>%
+   rename(IsBadBuy=.pred_1) %>%
+   mutate(RefId = test$RefId) %>%
+   select(RefId, IsBadBuy)
Error in `purrr::map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
ℹ With name: lightGBM_models_1_047.
Caused by error in `predictor$predict()`:
! Attempting to use a Booster which no longer exists. This can happen if you have called Booster$finalize() or if this Booster was saved with saveRDS(). To avoid this error in the future, use saveRDS.lgb.Booster() or Booster$save_model() to save lightgbm Boosters.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.`
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue was with storing the module. I was running the script in parallel with 13 of my 16  cores. When I ran the same script with less cores, there was no error.